# How can we 'loop' around files in Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have some tex files in a directory some of which are further organized into sub-directories.

```
input/
|
|-- one.tex
|-- two.tex
|-- sub1/
|   |
|   |-- three.tex
|           
|-- four.tex
|           
|-- sub2/
|   |
|   |-- five.tex
|           
|-- six.tex
```

I'm then running pdflatex on each of these tex files to create a corresponding pdf file (with an `"_out"` appended to its name without extension) having the same directory strucuture (possibly using `mkdir -p`) in an output directory.

```
output/
|
|-- one_out.pdf
|-- two_out.pdf
|-- sub1/
|   |
|   |-- three_out.pdf
|           
|-- four_out.pdf
|           
|-- sub2/
|   |
|   |-- five_out.pdf
|           
|-- six_out.pdf
```

I need to use `make` to update the corresponding pdf files if any of the tex files is modified.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

I did something like this, but it processes only one file (the first one).

```
SOURCE_DIR := input
BUILD_DIR := output

TEX_FILES := $(shell find $(SOURCE_DIR) -type f -name "*.tex")
PDF_FILES := $(patsubst $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.tex, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.pdf, $(TEX_FILES))

.PHONY: all

all: $(PDF_FILES)

# $< are inp files and $@ are out files
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.pdf: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.tex
    pdflatex -jobname=$(addsuffix _out,$(basename $@)) $<
```

PS: There are probably simpler ways to do this using other tools (and I would also be glad to know about them!) but I am looking for a way to get this done with gnu)make as a way to get to know it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you showed a small example with a few actual filenames and the actual output you get when you run make.  I can see no obvious reason in this makefile why it should stop with one file, unless all the other files already exist and are up to date.

I do see something strange but since I don't know anything about how `pdflatex` works, maybe it's expected:

```
# $< are inp files and $@ are out files
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.pdf: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.tex
        pdflatex -jobname=$(addsuffix _out,$(basename $@)) $<
```

Your comment (correctly) says that `$@` is the output file, but I don't see anywhere on your `pdflatex` command line where you tell `pdflatex` what output filename to use.  How does it figure that out?

Comment: pdflatex seems to use the `-jobname` option to accept output pdf name without the .pdf extension. So I gave it as `-jobname=$(addsuffix _out,$(basename $@))`. Is it wrong? `$@` has the complete output file path like `/path/to/output/one.tex` which after `basename` becomes `/path/to/output/one` which on `addsuffix` becomes `/path/to/output/one_out`. That was my train of thought.

Comment: As your comment says, make puts the file it expects your recipe to create into the `$@` variable, and that's the file that your recipe should create.  If your recipe creates some other filename that is not exactly `$@`, then that's not correct and make won't work: the next time you run make, it will look for the file `$@` and see it's not there (because the last time you ran make it created some other file) and it will run the command again.  Then the next time it will look for `$@` and see it's still not there, and run the command again... etc...

Comment: Oh.. That makes sense.. Let me fiddle around with my Makefile a bit more and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: And it is not giving out any output printed on the terminal really (at least the way it's written presently). That's why I didn't include any error message.

Comment: "Processes one file" is not the same as "not giving out any output"... I would like to see what you really get for a simple example.  The thing is, the issue with `$@` should not cause make to _skip_ a bunch of files that _should_ be created.  It will cause make to _rebuild_ files that shouldn't be rebuilt.  So if you're really seeing a situation where you have lots of files and make ignores them there's something else fishy.  I recommend you run `make --debug=b` and see if the output sheds any light on what's happening.

Comment: Just a quick hint for debugging makefiles -- you can try adding the line `$(info PDF_FILES: ($(PDF_FILES)))` to print a variable in the makefile (to make sure there's more than one file).   Also, you can run with `make -d` to see what make is doing.

Comment: Put another way, the makefile you have looks fine to me (other than the `$@` thing) so a problem related to make not building things must be for some reason you haven't shown us in your question.

Comment: I didn't know about about the `-d`, `info` and `--debug` (guess I hadn't even bothered to read the man well). Silly me had been trying to put in `echo` statements.. :-D  The example I got is a bit big though, so there is a lot of messages coming. Got to make an MCVE and work it out.

Comment: Using `-d` will give you a LOT of output that you probably don't care about.  Using `--debug=b` gives "basic" debugging which is probably enough to see what's happening.  Although, it can still be a lot of output.

Comment: It works now! The `--debug` option helped. Thanks a lot.